# viewDidAppear is NOT called but viewDidDisappear get called when pop

Tags: ios, uikit

```
class TestPlatfromViewController: UIViewController {
    var webVC: MyViewController!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        webVC = MyViewController()
        
        view.addSubview(webVC.view)
        
    }
}
```

I pushed a TestPlatfromViewController, and add MyViewController.view to self.view
MyViewController's viewWillAppear&viewDidAppear is NOT called
but MyViewController's viewWillDisappear&viewDidDisappear get called when I pop TestPlatfromViewController

following apple's documentation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear
Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621477-viewdiddisappear
Notifies the view controller that its view was removed from a view hierarchy.

so I get confused about add/remove view hierarchy
anyone gets some idea?

Why MyViewController's viewWillAppear&viewDidAppear is NOT called?

Comment: Please read [Implement a container view controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#1652844)

Answer (score 0):

It happened because you just added `MyViewController` as a subView of `TestPlatfromViewController`. If you want view controller life cycle functions get called, do something like:

```swift
...
webVC = MyViewController()
addChild(webVC)        
view.addSubview(webVC.view)
webVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

And why `viewWillDisappear` & `viewDidDisappear` get called. Because the `webVC` was about to be removed from a view hierarchy (pop it from navigation controller).